# Wordpress: Can't get URL in article tag with get_the_id();

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this markup

```
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($masonry_item_sizing); ?> style="background: url("<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sponsors_logo_file_url', true); ?>")">

                        <div class="inner-wrap animated">
                            <div class="post-content">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sponsors_logo_file_url', true); ?>">
                                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                    <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_location', true); ?></p>
                                    <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_date_time', true); ?></p>
                                <div class="post-meta <?php echo $extra_class; ?>">


                     </div><!--/post-meta-->


                    </div>
                    </div>
                   </article>
```

But in the article tag i can get the sponsors image url with this line:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sponsors_logo_file_url', true); ?>
```

but later inside the article tag it works just fine, here:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sponsors_logo_file_url', true); ?>">
```

In this img tag it returns the full image url, in the article tag it just returns: "http://example.com/events/" but not the direct link to the image.

Why does this happen and how can i solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's better use:

```
background-image: url()
```

instead

```
background: url("")
```

final code:

```
<?php $bg = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sponsors_logo_file_url', true); ?><article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($masonry_item_sizing); ?> style="background-image: url(<?php echo $bg; ?>)">
<div class="inner-wrap animated">
    <div class="post-content">
        <img src="<?php echo $bg; ?>">
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_location', true); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_date_time', true); ?></p>
        <div class="post-meta <?php echo $extra_class; ?>"></div><!--/post-meta-->
    </div>
</div>
```